# update a field from default user model django

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I am making an app that wants the default user model to be extended. I want to customize some of the fields, like adding some restrictions to the username. For example, the username must be between 4 to 16 characters and may contain lowercase alphabets, dashes and dots only.

My question is that how to update these fields in django? What is the best practice to do it. My model is below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    pass

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="following", symmetrical=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First need to add file forms.py to your project. Then import User model to your [forms.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) and models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

How to extend defaul user model you can see [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html).

For max and min symbols check use Forms.py, for example:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=16, min_length=4, required=True, error_messages= {"username_exists": "Username already exists."})
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=True, error_messages= {"invalid": "Please, enter correct E-mail"})
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

You can raise any error messages in your forms, look link higher.